# Verificar o status de um serviço na Amazon

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, amazon-aws

Bom minha duvida não é exatamente sobre código e sim como iniciar um projeto.

Minha duvida é a seguinte, tendo uma maquina na amazon, dentro da mesma existem varios servicos que estão rodando...o meu problema é q esses servicos podem "cair" e eu só perceber isso quando um cliente já detectou.
A duvida é existe algum meio de fazer um endpoit (se isso estiver certo), na maquina da amazon que eu bateria e verificasse se o sistema está ativo...não sei se é esse o caminho estou aberto a discussões

Comment: Talvez um serviço de notificações, cada vez que um dos sistemas falhasse enviava um email por ex, fazer desse sistema uma api comum entre os vários serviços

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara ainda. A aws é um serviço muito 'completo', eles não têm uma opção como essa? Os próprios serviços não oferecem isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O cloudwatch me parece ser uma boa opção para o seu problema, ele é composto de três serviços (Logs, Events e Alarm) e você pode enviar os logs das suas aplicações para o cloudwatch logs, criar métricas de filtros personalizados que identifiquem erro ou alteração, e com estas métricas é possível montar alarmes usando o Cloudwath Alarm ou Eventos do cloudwatch events que podem ser usados para reiniciar uma instancia, invocar outro serviço. Sugiro que dê um lida na documentação para entender melhor.

E caso esteja usando linux com Docker o ECS tem muitos recursos que melhoram aumentam a disponibilidade com muita automação.

Cloudwatch Logs (Filtros) - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html

ECS - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o serviço `AWS Cloudwatch` para criar um dashboard de seus serviços e que dispare alertas assim que um dos serviços sair do padrão.

Por exemplo, disparar um alerta quando o CPU da instância EC2 passar de 80%.

Além disso, se você quer fazer uma solução própria, pode usar a API deles ou ainda o Console (CLI). Com CLI você pode fazer um bash que consulte o status de um serviço obtido a partir de um comando.

Recomendo tentar usar o Cloudwatch associado a serviços de fora como Pingdom por exemplo. Se você mandar o Pingdom testar uma URL e ver se lá contém um texto que vem do banco de dados, em um único teste você confere o Webserver e o DBA.